# How to prove that $\forall \lambda\in(-\infty,+\infty)$,$\exists\alpha,\beta\in[a,b]$ satisfies $\lambda=\dfrac{f(\alpha)-f(\beta)}{\alpha-\beta}.$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f(x)\in C[a,b]$,and
$$\lim\limits_{x\to a+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=+\infty,\lim\limits_{x\to b-}\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}=-\infty.$$
Prove that $\forall \lambda\in(-\infty,+\infty)$,$\exists\alpha,\beta\in[a,b]$ satisfies $\lambda=\dfrac{f(\alpha)-f(\beta)}{\alpha-\beta}.$
This is the topic of our final exam last term. Here is my opinion:the conditions given by the title can be known that
$$\exists\delta_1>0,x\in(a,a+\delta_1),\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}>0\implies f(x)>f(a).$$
$$\exists\delta_2>0,x\in(b-\delta_2,b),\dfrac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b}<0\implies f(x)>f(b).$$
This shows that the maximum value of $f$ is not obtained at the endpoint, but the condition of differentiability is not given in the title, so I can't go on...

Comment: Showing the existence for $\lambda=0$ should be enough (otherwise let $g(x)=f(x)-\lambda x$). Since $f(x) increases from $f(a) and then decreases to $f(b)$ (as they both aren't maximums) so there exists two distinct points for which $f(\alpha)=f(\beta)$ .

Comment: My idea was to define $\psi(x,y)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} + \frac{f(y)-f(b)}{y-b}$. Then to say $\psi$ is continuous. But now i'm not sure if it is but could be helpful for someone.

Comment: @Oğuzhan Kılıç Thank you,but we haven't learned multivariable functions yet

Comment: @PNDas Thank you,，but in this case, it only needs the limit value to be greater than 0 or less than 0. Is it unnecessary for the problem to go to infinity?

Comment: @Hilbert1994 , the $\pm \infty$ part comes in my 1st sentence of the previous comment, when you show that $\lambda=0$ case is enough. You have to show that $\lim \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\infty\implies \lim \frac{g(x)-g(a)}{x-a}=\infty$ (and when a is replaced by b and $\infty$ by $-\infty$)

Comment: Hint: Consider the continuous functions $g(x):=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ on $(a,b]$ and $h(x):=\frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}$ on $[a,b).$ What is the union of the ranges of $g$ and $h$?

Comment: @ PNDas Because $\lambda$ is fixed, so $\lim\limits_{x\to a+}\frac{g(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=\lim\limits_{x\to a+}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-\lambda=+\infty$?

Comment: @Hilbert1994 Yes.